# Create 'X' with using CSS transform-origin and rotate

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transforms

I have a small issue, I need to rotate 2 spans and create a perfect 'X'.

I've created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/av5c7jL4/) for this. Can you guys help me?

I can't seem to get my head around how much should i transform origin...

HTML

```
<div class="toggle-btn">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

SASS

```
.toggle-btn {
  width: 38px;
  height: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  &:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
  }
  span {
    height: 2px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    transition: .15s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    &.toggled {
      &:nth-of-type(1) {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform-origin: 22px 9px;
      }
      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform-origin: 20px -5px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and JS

```
$('.toggle-btn').on('click',function(){
   $(this).find('span').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

Comment: seems fine to me - what exactly is your issue?

Comment: yea, but its always slightly offset... no matter what value i put in...

Comment: Use `translate` instead of `transform-origin`, see http://joren.co/sass-burger/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work. I had to adjust the `margin to 4px`. The rotation needs to come after the x/y translation because translating after the rotation appears to change the point of origin on which the element is rotating instead of origin of the element. You can observe this behavior by trying a large (100px) x-translation after the rotation.

```
.toggle-btn {
        width: 38px;
        height: 19px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 18px;
        text-align: center;
    overflow: show;
        &:after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }
        span {
            height: 2px;
            margin: 4px 0px;
            background: #333;
            width: 38px;
            display: block;
            transition: .15s ease-in;
            text-align: center;
            &.toggled {
                &:nth-of-type(1) {
                    transform: translate(0px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
                }
                &:nth-of-type(2) {
                    transform: translate(0px, -3px) rotate(45deg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```